# What process do you use to determine the "why" of web searchers goal for your "transactional keywords"?

Tags: seo, search-results, conversions, local-seo

SEO starts with the intentions of the person using the search engine.

What ever the web searcher intended to gain from typing their search keyword/phrase into google will help you understand what needs to appear in their search results to entice them to click on your money generating link (a link that generates a sale, which was found using a transactional keyword).

The web searcher's intent is "why" they performed the search in the first place.

Ambiguities between why a web searcher searched and if a particular transactional keyword causes them to click the link when it is not related to their intent, results in wasted Pay-Per-Clicks; and this is why knowing the intention (the why) of the web searcher's search is important.
(Am I confusing AdWords with SEO here?)

Additionally, the text displayed in an individual search result (the page title, and the slug text) can match the web searcher's intention and cause them to click the link resulting in a sale, which is what we as webmasters want.

So as webmasters, I ask you, what do you do to determine why people are searching for your transactional keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get analytical. It 's too complex and chaotic. That 's why people do A/B testing and find in practice what works best.

Comment: So A/B Testing is whenever you sit down with a user to ask them how they think?

Comment: Could you define what A/B testing means: it would make your answer a lot better (A/B testing is when you try two keywords, see which one performs better, and target the higher performing keyword).

Comment: Okay so it's like when you go the eye doctor with the lenses and they say "Which is better one, or two?" and then when two wins, two becomes three, they introduce a new lense and say "Which is better three or four"...and so forth....

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it is logic: for example, if people search for `cheap web hosting`, then they are probably looking to buy web hosting. The word `cheap` implies that they are looking to buy something, because cheap is a price and when people are searching for a price then they probably are searching for a product, and when people search for a product they usually want to buy it.

However, in cases when a user searches for something like `blender`, then it get's more complicated. In this case, I usually look at the top results for `blender`. Google tries to get the results that someone is looking for in the first page: otherwise Google's users will get annoyed and leave. According to the Google results for blender, users are either searching for [blender](http://www.blender.org/): the 3D creation program, or blender: a machine that mixes things together.

Because there are two possible definitions, there are two options someone can take:

1. Target the keyword `blender` with either something related to the software or the machine, and lose clicks because half of the people are looking for the other definition of blender.
2. Target a keyword like `blender 3d`, or `cheap blender`, that is more specific, and takes the guesswork out of guessing which blender the user was referring to, but lose some traffic because those keywords receive less traffic.

If there was only one definition, than this would be much more easier, and you wouldn't have to worry about this.